# saving an 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object

Tags: python, lxml, pickle

I've spent the last couple of days getting to grips with the basics of lxml; in particular using lxml.html to parse websites and create an ElementTree of the content. Ideally, I want to save the returned ElementTree so that I can load it up and experiment with it, without having to parse the website every time I modify my script. I assumed that pickling would be the way to go, however I'm now beginning to wonder. Although I am able to retrieve an ElementTree object after pickling...

```
type(myObject)
```

returns

```
<class 'lxml.etree._ElementTree'>
```

the object itself appears to be 'empty', since none of the subsequent method/attribute calls I make on it yield any output.

My guess is that pickling isn't appropriate here, but can anyone suggest an alternative?

(In case it matters, the above is happening in: python3.2, lxml 2.3.2, snow-leopard))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are already dealing with XML, and `lxml` is great at parsing XML. So I think
the simplest thing to do would be to serialize to XML:

To write to file:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

filename = '/tmp/test.xml'
myobject.write(filename)
```

To call the `write` method, note that `myobject` must be an `lxml.etree._ElementTree`. If it is an
`lxml.etree._Element`, then you would need
`myobject.getroottree().write(filename)`.

To parse from file name/path, file object, or URL:

```
myobject = ET.parse(file_or_url)
```

To parse from string:

```
myobject = ET.fromstring(content)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately my understanding of lxml, element trees, and the like, is so sketchy that I don't actually understand the suggestions you have made. I've tried hard to wade through the lxml manual over the past couple of days but have gotten nowhere, so I'm going to leave this project for the time being.

Comment: The suggested write-method got me an error in python3, but changing from 'w' to 'wb' made it work.

Answer (score 16):

lxml is a C library - libxml to be precise - and the object probably don't support python pickling or any other kind of serialization - except serializing them to XML.

So you'll either have to keep them in memory, or re-parse the XML fragments you need, I assume.

Comment: Confirming that `pickle` returns 'TypeError: can't pickle _Element objects'... which is how I found this question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you can pickle lxml instances, but what I did because I was in a similar situation was I pickled the object instances that would build the tree.

Each instance and its child had a function to build the Element tree. So I would simply pickle/cache the Python object, fetch it from cache, and then call the build functions to get my Element tree.

Comment: Thanks Bartek. As I mention in my response above, It's become clear that I really don't enough about element trees and and lxml to make use of your answer, or the other answers posted here. That said, I have at least confirmed my suspicions that pickling is of no use in this example.