# Error when using pickle, TypeError: can't pickle ElementBase objects

Tags: python, lxml, pickle

so I have some code that scrapes some html concerning financial data from yahoo finance using the lxml package and does various operations on it. I create a dictionary that contains all the relevant information I need and I have been trying to save the object using pickle as it takes roughly 5 minutes to create it each time. However when I try and use the following lines of code, I get the error in my title above:

```
file = open('file.obj', 'w')
pickle.dump(headline_dictionary, file)
```

As I have little experience with pickle, I think the issue comes from the fact that the ElementBase objects created by the lxml packages can't be pickled. If this is the case, is there another way I can save my object, or am I using pickle in the wrong way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `headline_dictionary` (type?), also, please provide the error traceback.

Comment: Yes, likely you can't pickle that, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8274474/797744

Comment: Pickling lxml won't work. Any reason why you don't want to save this data directly as XML?

Comment: @emh because this data is part of a bigger object (e.g. a dictionary with other fields) and you want to keep the structure. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as you. To persist your dictionary as a pickled object, you'll first need to cast the dictionary's values (aka data scraped through lxml) as strings or integers for example. That's your workaround.

Example code, where value has been scraped through lxml:

```
dict["key"] = str(value)
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer, could you detail it more supporting it with some code?