# serialize beautiful soup and xpath tree in python

Tags: python, serialization, xpath, beautifulsoup

First, there's the python script to get xpath tree and beautiful soup given url.

```
# get tree
def get_tree(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
    return tree

# get soup
def get_soup(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    return soup
```

We often need tree and soup to navigate the source code page and extract useful information we need. But we could frequently have bug and then fix it, or we changed mind on what information we really need. So in this sense, serialize the soup and xpath tree could be a good idea and we can do it ahead for only once.
But how could we serialize beautiful soup and xpath tree in python?
Is there any database can store soup or tree object? If not, any example code to serialize them manually?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you want to store the soup variable so that you don't have to request the url over and over while debugging. Seems like you are not aware of the [python pickle module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) which can serialize any object. It's not without its problems, but for your debugging needs, it can help you and it's really simple.

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(soup, open("soup.pickle","w"))
# then when you need to load the soup again
soup = pickle.load(open("soup.pickle","r"))
```

And now you got yourself a pickle soup! :D

Comment: The only downside is that I can't load pickle from script in other language like java

Comment: I try to pickle tree. But I got error like this: raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle _Element objects

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274438/saving-an-lxml-etree-elementtree-object

Comment: Unfortunately one can't pickle large beautifulsoups. The soup of a 5MB file needs more recursion than the hard limit. For smaller files (which I guess is most of them) it's good though!

Comment: @Mark to avoid this limit you can encode the soup into a string - see https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2eoeji/how_to_turn_a_beautifulsoup_object_into_a_string/

Comment: @AddingColor Probably easier to just save the requested url's content then, but you're right, you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

when you use lxml all simple:

```
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
i_need_element = tree.xpath('//a[@class="shared-components"]/@href')
```

but when use BeautifulSoup BS4 all simple too:

- first remove "//" and "@"
- second - add star before "="

try this magic:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
i_need_element = soup.select ('a[class*="shared-components"]')
```

as you see, this does not support sub-tag, so i remove "/@href" part